# How does inheritance behave with static member variables

Tags: c++

I have an inheritance tree with the need to declare a per-class UUID.
I chose to implement it as a "static constexpr const char *" expression.

However, I expected the following code to fail (I want any interface implementer mandatory provides an UUID field), but it compiles fine with clang (although the UUID is commented in I interface).

I expect the code to fail as I want any interface implementer that derives IBase to explicitly provide its own dedicated UUID for its interface.

Moreover, I expect it to fail as I thought a static member variable is a class member, hence not related to inheritance behavior (I expect a static member variable scope to be only the class it was defined in).

What is the explanation ?

```
class C {
public:
    C() = default;
    ~C() = default;
    template <class T>
    void addElement(T* componentThis, const char * name);

private:
    std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*> m_elements;
};

template <class T>
void C::addElement(T* elementThis, const char * name)
{
    boost::uuids::uuid elementId = toUUID(T::UUID);
    m_elements[elementId]=elementThis;
}

class IBase {
public:
    virtual ~IBase() = default;

    static constexpr const char * UUID = "F601639A-17D0-4A25-B85A-DF5753357A0A";
};

class I : public virtual IBase {
public:
    virtual ~I() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;

  //  static constexpr const char * UUID = "CEE87DFF-07C3-42B7-AFA8-047CDAFBD177";
};

class E : public C, public I {
public:
    E() { addElement<I>(this,"E"); }
    ~E() = default;
    inline void f() override { std::cout<<"Calling f"<<std::endl; }

    static constexpr const char * UUID = "3126D74D-7BE4-4AD4-93FB-D2616859C44F";
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  E e;
  e.f();
}
```

Comment: why do you expect it to fail ? being IBase a public base, IBase::UUID gets looked-up ...

Comment: You're going to have to explain why you expect the code to fail.   When valid code compiles, a correct explanation is validity of the code.   If you think the code exhibits errors, you need to explain what you believe those errors to be.

Comment: Edited. But indeed, IBase::UUID gets looked-up. I wonder however if there is no contradiction between name lookup and static member variable ?